# Microsoft-Cognitive Face API Enpoint Issue

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I created a cognitive service face api and my endpoint doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't give the location within the address. This is listed as my endpoint: https://kbob.cognitiveservices.azure.com/

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace emobe
{
    public class CognoF
    {
        const string subscriptionKey = "xxxx_VALUE_HIDDEN_xxxx";
        const string uriBase = "https://kbob.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";

        async public Task<emotions> MakeAnalysisRequest(byte[] imageData)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
            string requestParameters = "?returnFaceAttributes=emotion";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
            string uri = uriBase + requestParameters;

            HttpResponseMessage response;

            // Request body. Posts a locally stored JPEG image.
            //byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(imageData))
            {
                // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
                // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                // Execute the REST API call.
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

                // Get the JSON response.
                string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                // Display the JSON response.
                Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n");
                //Console.WriteLine(JsonPrettyPrint(contentString));

                // For that you will need to add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization
                var jsonReader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contentString), new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

                // For that you will need to add reference to System.Xml and System.Xml.Linq
                var root = XElement.Load(jsonReader);
                Console.WriteLine(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion").Value);
                Console.WriteLine(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/anger").Value);

                emotions emos = new emotions();
                emos.anger = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/anger").Value);
                emos.contempt = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/contempt").Value);
                emos.disgust = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/disgust").Value);
                emos.fear = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/fear").Value);
                emos.happiness = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/happiness").Value);
                emos.neutral = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/neutral").Value);
                emos.sadness = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/sadness").Value);
                emos.surprise = decimal.Parse(root.XPathSelectElement("//faceAttributes/emotion/surprise").Value);

                return emos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by " It doesn't give the location within the address." ? Can you add more details of your implementation?

Comment: I'm told it should be "northcentralus.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face. Or something similar.

Comment: When I use it in Visual Studio, it's throwing an error that seems to be related to the endpoint.

Comment: Add details of your implementation so that we can help. There are 2 types of endpoints: the one using the region name, the other ones using your subdomain as you are mentioning. Both work, you just have to pass the right information given how you implement it

Comment: @NicolasR can I attach somewhere?\

Comment: please remove your last comment pointing to onedrive, as your code contains your key...

Comment: @NicolasR Thanks, I did remove it. I had deleted it from a previous version but forgot when I sent the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to POST your request to `uri` which is `uriBase + requestParameters;`

So its value is "https://kbob.cognitiveservices.azure.com/?returnFaceAttributes=emotion"

Here you are missing a part of the service url, which is the face root called "/face/v1.0/{method}". In your case it looks like you want to use "detect" method, so you should have "https://kbob.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceAttributes=emotion"

Add "/face/v1.0/detect" and it should work

If you are not sure about the urls, have a look to the console: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console